# How to recover Android key file in Phonegap build?

Tags: phonegap-build, android-keystore

So I stopped using Phonegap build and started signing my app in a different way (I'm building using Eclipse and stupidly made a new keystore file), so Google is not letting me upload my most recent APK because it was signed differently.  How do I recover the key file from Phonegap build that I have been using, and if I can't do this, how do I replicate the key file exactly as it was?

Answer (score 0):

## Signing Your Applications

> **Android** requires that all apps be digitally signed with a certificate before they can be installed. Android uses this certificate to identify the author of an app, and the certificate does not need to be signed by a certificate authority.... [**More...**](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#studio)

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#studio

In your **eclipse** follow this steps

***Package Explorer > Your_project right click > Android Tools > Export Signed Application Package***

Comment: Yes, and I did this.  However, I signed the old app with a different certificate, so wouldn't I have to use that keystore file?